# Evolution hangs at launch

Tags: email, evolution

I have a pretty straightforward install running exclusively 16.04 on a HP laptop. It's a fairly fresh install with not much else done.

I've installed Evolution as my preferred email client, however everytime I start it up, Evolution hangs for minutes at a time. Then works like a charm...

No errors given, no clue as to what it might be. Can any gods of ubuntu render assistance?

Thank you